# PHP: Can You Pass Include Through a Function?

Tags: php, include

Is it at all possible to **include** a file through a function? I don't mean returning the contents as a string. I'd like to create my own **custom include method**, but right now it doesn't seem possible.

For instance, PHP's **include** method outputs file contents. I'd like to output file contents, but run them through another function first.

For example:

```
function include_filter($file){
    include($file);
}
include_filter($file);
```

This example does not use additional functionality, because my primary question here is how to include through a function at all. You can see the issue.

If I include through a function such as **include_filter**, the code will be included locally inside the function only, not at the line the function was called (**line 4** in the example).

Comment: Can you please be more specific about what your custom include method actually does besides simply including the file?

Comment: Are you trying to execute a particular script inside `$file`?

Comment: Include injects code wherever it is called; should we not be able to inject our own code from a function wherever we wish? I want to pull a file, add some data to it, then inject it where the include_filter is. So if "include" injects the file contents, I want "include_filter" to inject the file contents exactly the same way but with some more PHP code with it. I need it as a function to streamline the process

Answer (score 0):

The `include` statement does not output the file contents. However, it does *evaluate* the file you're including, so if that file contains any `echo` statements then yes, those are executed the moment you include that file.

You can use an output buffer to catch that output and do something with it before re-`echo`'ing it:

**included_file.php**:

```
<?php
echo "This came from an included file.";
```

**main_file.php**:

```
<?php
function include_filter($path) {
    ob_start();
    include $path;
    $output = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    echo str_replace("an included file", "a filter function", $output);
}

include_filter("included_file.php");
// will output "This came from a filter function."
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/2XkL7

Comment: Thank you very much Rick, yet I need to inject parsed PHP code right from the function call, not the string return from the file. Any ideas?

Comment: Ahh I see, I misinterpreted your question. In that case, no. Anything included is imported into the active scope. So from within a function, it is all imported into the function scope and not available outside that function (except for functions and classes, these are global). It's not possible to change that behavior. This is actually explicitly documented around example #2 in [the documentation](https://secure.php.net/include).